# how to refresh the source tab when the current tab is closed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-tab, workspaceapi

I have a button "Create Activity" in a lightning component (say LC1) on the case lightning record page. When I click that button, an another lightning component (say LC2) opens as a sub tab with some fields to be filled. Once all details are entered, save (Used Lightning Data Service) button is clicked.

Issue here is, I need to close the LC2 which in turn should refresh the LC1 so that the related list in LC1 will display the created record from LC2, which is not happening.

I have tried 2 ways:

1. `window.location.reload();`

   - When I use this approach, LC2 is getting closed, the browser tab is refreshed but the LC2 is opening again and this should not happen.(Not sure why this is happening)
2. `workSpaceAPI.refreshTab`

   - When I use this, LC2 is closed but LC1 is not refreshed. My doubt here is, once the LC2 is closed, does LC1 consider the refresh request from the closed LC2?

---

```
saveActivity : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('field values'+JSON.stringify(component.get("v.simpleNewActivity")));
    component.find("activityRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
            // record is saved successfully
            var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            resultsToast.setParams({
                "title": "Saved",
                "message": "The record was saved."
            });
            resultsToast.fire();
            var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
           //caseTabId is the source Tab Id
            var caseTabId = component.get("v.caseTabId");
            workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
                var focusedTabId = response.tabId;     
                //window.location.reload(); 
                workspaceAPI.refreshTab({
                    tabId:caseTabId, 
                    includeAllSubtabs: true
                });
                workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId}); 
            }) 
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });  
        } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // handle the incomplete state
            console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
        } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
            // handle the error state
            console.log('Problem saving contact, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        } else {
            console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the lighting data service event created by the second component in the first component by adding the below aura handler to the first component

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.init}"/>
```

where the action tag in the handler calls the javascript function that calls the apex class that gets the data